# Trying to send form via jQuery.post method and getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<FormData> has no method 'serialize "

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to call my upload method which is going to take send the form using jQuery post method but while trying following getting following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'serialize

Code:

```
     function upload() {
        var dfg = new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);
        alert(dfg);
        jQuery
    .post(
            'uplAttachment',
            {
                dfg: dfg.serialize()
            },
            function (data) {
                var la = data;
                if (la == null | la == '') {
                    alert("success");
                }
                else {
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
    }
```

jsp page :

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 60px;">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file:
            <input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileAttachment"/><br/><br/>
                <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px;">
                    <input style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="" onclick="upload()" class="dialogbox" type="submit" value="Upload Report" />
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$(dfg).serialize()` make a jQuery wrapper.

Comment: leave it just posted an answer you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating object of FormData like "dfg".

```
var dfg=new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);
```

there is no serialize() method has defined in FormData so you should pass abject though ajax only.

OR

```
    function upload()
    {
        var dfg = new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uplAttachment',
            data: dfg,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you meant to say no need to use serialize method,directly i should pass dfg variable ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: if i pass dfg variable directly(without serializing) then following error is coming "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation      jquery-1.8.3.js:7219
jQuery.param.add      jquery-1.8.3.js:7219
buildParams           jquery-1.8.3.js:7277
buildParams           jquery-1.8.3.js:7272
jQuery.param          jquery-1.8.3.js:7239
jQuery.extend.ajax    jquery-1.8.3.js:7872
jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function)"

Comment: Please have a look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
function upload() {
var dfg = new FormData(jQuery('form')[0]);
```

change to this:

pass the current element's context when click on the input:

```
onclick="upload(this)"
```

then update your function like this:

```
function upload(el) {
var dfg = jQuery(el).closest('form');
```

---

So your final code should be like this:

#### HTML:

```
<input style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="" onclick="upload(this)" 
       class="dialogbox" type="submit" value="Upload Report" />
```

#### jQuery:

```
function upload(el) {
   var dfg = jQuery(el).closest('form');
   alert(dfg);
   jQuery.post('uplAttachment', {
      dfg: dfg.serialize()
   }, function (data) {
      var la = data;
      if (la == null | la == '') {
          alert("success");
      } else {
          alert("failed");
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: tried your solution and got following error on browser console             500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.3.js:8435
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery-1.8.3.js:8435
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.3.js:7987
jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.3.js:7511
uplAttachment